# Delete and rename all array keys which start with a given string

Tags: php

I have an associated array.  I would like to be able to delete all elements whose key's start with a given string of any given length.  I would also like to be able to rename all keys which start with a given string to a new string appended by the remainder of the key.  For instance, given the initial array, deleting all elements which start with "zzz" will result in the deleted array, and renaming all elements which start with "zzz" with "yyyy" will result in the renamed array.

```
Initial Array
Array
(
    [zzzaaaa] => 1
    [bbbb] => 1
    [cccc] => 1
    [zzzdddd] => 1
)

Deleted Array
Array
(
    [bbbb] => 1
    [cccc] => 1
)

Renamed Array
Array
(
    [yyyyaaaa] => 1
    [bbbb] => 1
    [cccc] => 1
    [yyyydddd] => 1
)
```

PS.  The purpose of doing so is to store URSs, and thus if a sub-directory is deleted or renamed, all references to other directories and files are also deleted or renamed.

EDIT.  This is what I ended up going with.  Don't know if there is a quicker/less code way.

```
//Delete
$length=strlen($key_string);
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, $length)==$key_string) {unset($myArray[$key]);}
}

//Rename
$length=strlen($key_string);
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, $length)==$key_string) {
        $myArray[$new_key_string.substr($key, $length)] = $myArray[$key_string];
        unset($myArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through the array, substring each index, compare to string, if match, delete from array, if not, move on.

Comment: `preg_grep('/^zzz/', array_keys($array))`?

Comment: @RUJordan  Yes,I thought of that solution.  Didn't know if there was some slicker solution using something like `array_filter()` or `array_search()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk.php) to do it. However I would not manipulate the array while iterating over it. It's better to create a new array which will store the results.

Here's what I would do:

```
    //You input array
    $array=array( "zzzaaaa" => 1, "bbbb" => 1, "cccc" => 1, "zzzdddd" => 1);

    //Array for storing the results
    $new_array=array();

    //print original array
    print_r($array);

    //walk over array and determine if it starts with zzz
    array_walk($array, function($val, $key) use(&$array, &$new_array){
        if(strpos($key, "zzz")===0){
            $new_array[preg_replace("/zzz/","yyyy", $key)]=$val;
        }else{
            $new_array[$key]=$val;
        }
    });
    print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [zzzaaaa] => 1 [bbbb] => 1 [cccc] => 1 [zzzdddd] => 1 ) 
Array ( [yyyyaaaa] => 1 [bbbb] => 1 [cccc] => 1 [yyyydddd] => 1 )
```

([link to example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b237eccfe68f2a3af6fe6a0f15a9bad901541642))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
function stripOrChange(&$array,$parse,$changeto=false){
 foreach($array as $key=>$item){
  if(strpos($key,$parse) !== false && $key != $parse){
   if($changeto == 'true'){
   $array[$parse] = $array[$key];
   unset($array[$key]);
   }else{
   unset($array[$key]);  
   }
  }
 }
}
```

[working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/421dc86b6c348cedfd8f157b2b20b072b46c4a8a)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to sandbox you referred as an example. Didn't knew that page yet and it's great if you're on a computer with no phpsh installed.

Comment: You should also now about http://jsfiddle.net/ , which is cool to use and show javascript/jquery, or http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test and show sql commands